# Mustache template. Why is there no output

Tags: jquery, templates, mustache

On the screen I can output `Team:` but the corresponding `teamName` does not output at all. Can anyone suggest a reason for this?

```
var $teams = $('#info');
var template = '<td> Team: {{standings.standing[0].teamName}} </td>';
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': '0fc841d392274cb5a26804330ac11e98'
    },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/401/leagueTable',
    success: function(standings) {
        var output = Mustache.render(template, standings);
        $teams.append(output);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="u-max-full-width">
        <thead>
                <th>Serie A</th>
                <th>W</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>L</th>
                <th>Goals</th>
                <th>Diff</th>
                <th>Pt</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="info"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/bigheed/pen/OMpOza?editors=001

Comment: What data is returned in the `standings` variable? We can't help you without seeing that.

Comment: The data returned can be seen here http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/401/leagueTable in json format

Answer (score 0):

I changes this two line and its works,

```
var template = '{{#data}} <td> Team: {{teamName}} </td> {{/data}}';
var output = Mustache.to_html(template, {data:standings.standing});
```

Comment: This does work, although I don't want to loop over the entire 'data' object.

Comment: if you don't want to loop over data object, you may try like this, {data:standings.standing[0]} and change  template {{data.teamName}}